# expo error "possible undandled promise rejection"

Tags: django, react-native, django-rest-framework, expo

I am making an app using react-native with expo and django rest-framework, this error appears when I want to fetch the data from my database, I leave below how I take the data from my localhost to see if someone can solve it, try using the android studio emulator and a personal device and the same error occurs.
[EXPO ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDdZy.png)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import DataList from "../components/data-list";

const ListScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

    const [data, setData] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData()
    }, [])

    const fetchData = async() => {
        const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/prices/')
        const data = await response.json()
        setData(data)
    }

    return(
        <View>
            <DataList data={data}/>
        </View>
    );
}

export default ListScreen
```

It works correctly for another person with this same code, but it doesn't work for me in particular.
:(

Answer (score 0):

This error shows up because your `fetch` request can get `rejected` and you don't manage this case in your code.

When you are using the `async/await` feature of Javascript you should wrap the await calls always in a try/catch block to handle both cases `resolving` and `rejecting` the `Promise`. `React Native` just wants to give you the hint to write clean code and think about the case something goes wrong during your `fetch` call

Change your code like this:

```
const fetchData = async() => {
   try{
      const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/prices/')
      // below code gets executed just in case the fetch promise is resolved
      const data = await response.json()
      setData(data)
   }catch(e){
      // do something in case your fetch promise gets rejected
   }
}
```